# Angular md-nav-bar to reflect current route

Tags: angularjs

I use the following md-nav-bar:

```
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" aria-label="nav">
    <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/overview" name="overview">Übersicht</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/howitworks" name="howitworks">So funktioniert's</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/startnow" name="startnow">Jetzt loslegen</md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>
```

I would like the nav bar to reflect the current URL's route, so if the URL is http://somewhere/#/howitworks the second md-nav-item should be highlighted. So far I was not able to find out how to go about it.

Comment: An easy way is to add an ng-class="{YOUR_CLASS: $location.path() === "YOUR_PATH"}" on each item

Comment: `$location.path()` does not seem to work. As your suggestion did not work, I tried outputting the path using `{{$location.path()}}`, but it was empty/undefined.

Comment: is $location injected in your controller ?

Comment: Yes, it is: `function AppCtrl($scope, $location) {..}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I can't post a comment, so I have to post this as a response)

$location.path() is not working for you because the path is not changing, but the hash (the part after the #). You have to use $location.hash() instead.

```
ng-class="{YOUR_CLASS: $location.hash() === 'YOUR_PATH'}"
```

If you prefer to use `md-selected-nav-item`, as I do, you can add a function to the controller to extract the name of the tab from the hash:

```
this.getTabName() {
    return $location.hash().replace(/(^#\/|\/$)/g, '');
}
```

Then your can use it in your view in this way:

```
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="getTabName()" aria-label="nav">
    <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/overview" name="overview">Übersicht</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/howitworks" name="howitworks">So funktioniert's</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/startnow" name="startnow">Jetzt loslegen</md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works when entering a URL in the browser, but if I change the route dynamically with something like `$location.path('/signup');` it won't work as it would have to watch the route changes probably.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **`ui-sref-active`**

For example, we have states called home, about and contact. If we wanted to add an active class to each if the state is active, we just do the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="contact" ui-sref-active="active">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now if the current state matches the state in `ui-sref`, the class provided in ui-sref-active will activate. Then we can style that to our heart’s content.

**md-nav-sref** transitions to ui-sref as seen in the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavItem)

Comment: Thanks! However, `md-nav-sref` does not seem to work for me, neither with `md-nav-sref="about"` nor with `md-nav-sref="#/about"`, so I have been using `md-nav-href="#/about"` instead. Any idea why sref does not work?

Answer (score 0):

After wandering around a little, I come up with this solution. 
Hope it may help someone in future.

**## Solution: catch transition event** 
Environment:

```
Angularjs: v1.7.6
Angular-ui-route: v1.0.20
```

In html:

```
<div ng-cloak ng-controller="navCtrl as $ctrl">    
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="$ctrl.currentNavItem">
                <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="client.TopPage" name="client.TopPage”>TOP PAGE</md-nav-item>
                <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="client.SecondPage" name="client.SecondPage”>SECOND PAGE</md-nav-item>
            </md-nav-bar>
</div>
```

In controller.js:

```
navController.$inject = ['$state', '$transitions']
   function navController($state,$transitions){
        var $ctrl = this;    

        // Catch change state event and update
        $transitions.onSuccess({}, function() {
            $ctrl.currentNavItem = $state.current.name;
        });
    }
```